# How to load extra fields into a model from thinking-sphinx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I use thinking-sphinx like this :

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_index do
    indexes title
    indexes comments.message, as: :comment_message
    indexes category_projects.description, as: :category_description
  end

  class << self
    def text_search(word)
      ThinkingSphinx.search(word, include: :comments)
    end
  end
end
```

When I do this `Project.text_search('test')` it works but I want to do this :

```
@projects = Project.text_search('test')
@projects.each do |project|
  puts project.comment_message
end
```

For the moment I have this message :

```
undefined method `comment_message' for #<ThinkingSphinx::Search:0x000000057e11c0>
    from /home/dougui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf@comment_my_projects/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-b293abdbdf0c/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:185:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /home/dougui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf@comment_my_projects/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/dougui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf@comment_my_projects/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/dougui/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194-perf@comment_my_projects/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So, how to load fields into a model from thinking-sphinx?

I didn't find anything one the doc.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if @projects is not nil ?

Comment: Yes, I have result in @projects,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on the TS mailing list as well, but essentially, the fields aren't returned by Sphinx, so you just need to refer to the associations/columns that the fields are built from:

```
projects.each do |project|
  puts project.comments.message.join("\n")
end
```